# Monotouch - Use of Application class as storage of common objects

Tags: xamarin.ios

To communicate between views and objects persistant information, for example the username and choice of font size for display, is it considered good form to put these onto the Application object, or is it more efficient to put them into static singletons?

For example:

```
public class Application
    {
        static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main (args);
        }

        public static Username {get;set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any difference performance-wise between putting static objects into the Application vs singletons vs static classes.

For things like Colors and fonts, I usually prefer to create static classes to hold each type of object, so for example I usually write this:

```
public static class Colors {
    public static Color ToolbarColor = Color.Black;
    ..
}
```

This makes it easier to change colors around the entire app without having to be searching around everywhere. I do the same thing for fonts, images, etc.

Comment: +1 I do this also and going this route has the added benefits of being easy to reuse.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. I have used your Blog code in dozens of iPhone apps now. Keep up the great community support!